# sql count multiple columns in a m/n relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling with three related tables where I like to display **the number of domains** and **the number of addresses** a certain code is used. I have three tables:

**table_locations**:

```
ID | domain       | address             
======================================
 1 | example.com  | example.com/siteA   
 2 | example.com  | example.com/siteB   
 3 | example.com  | sub.example.com     
 4 | whatever.com | whatever.com 
 5 | foobar.com   | foobar.com/site123  
 6 | foobar.com   | foobar.com/site
```

**table_codes**:

```
ID | code        
==========
 1 | ABC 
 2 | DEF
```

**table_codes_locations**:

```
code_id | location_id        
=====================
 1      | 1 
 1      | 2    
 1      | 3
 1      | 4
 2      | 5 
 2      | 6
```

### What I like to get (EDIT: when limiting the query to address = 'example.com'):

```
ID | code  | domaincount | addresses      
=====================================
 1 | ABC   |  2          | 3
 2 | DEF   |  1          | 2
```

<del>which means code "ABC" is used on one domain (example.com) and on three subdomains; "DEF" is used on one domain and on two subdomains</del>

The domaincount shows the number of domains the code is used while the addresses displays the number of addresses of a given domain the code is used. I'm not sure if this is even possible with a single statement

Comment: Your edit has only confused the question.  `example.com` only has one code in the code locations table.

Comment: Sorry, basically I would like to know how often the code is used in general (on which domains) and how often it is used on a certain domain (which is known)

Comment: My answer below should return the desired results in the question.  However, this has nothing to do with `example.com`.  The answer to that question is probably conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `count(distinct)`:

```
select c.code, count(distinct l.domain) as numdomains,
       count(l.address) as numaddress
from codes c left outer join
     code_locations cl
     on c.id = cl.code_id left outer join
     locations l
     on l.id = cl.location_id
group by c.code;
```

EDIT:

Perhaps:

```
select c.code, count(distinct l.domain) as numdomains,
       count(l.address) as numaddress,
       sum(case when l.address like '%example.com% then 1 else 0 end) as NumAddressExample
from codes c left outer join
     code_locations cl
     on c.id = cl.code_id left outer join
     locations l
     on l.id = cl.location_id
group by c.code;
```

Comment: nice, so I also can remove the second distinct like `...count(l.address) as numaddress...`? Any (dis)advantage?

Comment: `count()` is more efficient than `count(distinct)`.  They will be the same if the addresses are all different.

Comment: Ok, thanks, One more thing came up: Can I limit only the address to a certain domain? Like `WHERE l.address = 'example.com'` without losing the number of domains?

Comment: Thanks I had that already, but it gives me only one `numdomains` while it should be two (used on example.com and on whatever.com). I know the added where clause limits this but I would like to have "used on two domains and on three addresses where domain = example.com" Hope that makes sense